# How can future Mars colonists combat intelligence loss?

Tags: hard-science, space-colonization, planets

Earth is more massive than Mars, so people on Martian soil would definitely suffer some health issues due to weaker gravity. Blood circulation is badly affected as heart muscles starts to deteriorate; as a result of the lower blood pressure, with less nutrients/oxygen to fuel our brain cells I reckon the neurons will be starved. For example astronauts on board the International Space Station(ISS) periodically perform intensive exercises with specially designed machines in order to keep their bodies fit; however this is not a long term solution and they will eventually return to Earth.

Will people on Mars be able to adapt and cope with the weak gravity? How can they prevent deterioration of their brain? Are there any drugs or prescriptions for these Martians or they will be staying in specialized quarters mimicking the conditions on Earth?

Comment: Do you have any studies that prove that this would happen on a significant level at all?

Comment: But lower gravity means that weaker hearts can still do the job.

Comment: @HDE 226868 actually no, that's only my opinion(reckon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot af time to spend, go read Kim Stanley Robinson's books about mars colonisation. It's very well documented about the human race adapting on mars (great books, by the way !)

To resume : for earth people on the first generation, a lot of exercises are needed to preserve an healthy body (but not as much as on the ISS, as there is only a weaker gravity, not no gravity at all). The body will fully recover after a few weeks on earth (despite a little muscle atrophy, but no brain issues)

But the future martian generation will likely adapt itself to the gravity quite quickly.

Comment: I don't think this answer satisfies [the requirements](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/defining-the-boundaries-of-the-hard-science-tag) of the [tag:hard-science] tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a rotating parabolic ground to create artifical gravity**.

You create a normal bubble on mars until Mars is terraformed and the atmosphere is breathable. Inside the structure is a giant parabolic
surface which rotates causing a centrifugal force. The form of the surface
guarantees that the sum of both gravity and centrifugal force is exactly
perpendicular to the surface, it feels like normal gravity if you are standing. The amount of force depends on the distance from the center, at a specific distance it equals earth gravity.

Under the rotating platform where people sleep are the exits to Mars which can be accessed through the rotation axis containing elevator and stairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a few assumptions with regards to how we will be affected biologically, but you could well be right. On ISS they have no gravity, not low gravity. If the low gravity was such a problem then I've thought of a simple solution.

**Live Underwater**

It just occurred to me that they'd need to be living in specialised quarters anyway due to lack of atmosphere, so why not fill up some huge tanks and live underwater for part of the day? Or maybe just sleep under water. With tanks the right size, this would be an easy way to mimic the pressure of Earth's gravity on the blood and heart. Moving underwater while wearing a suit is also more difficult so might additionally help with muscle atrophy.

Comment: let me think about it... something is fishy

Comment: The OP is marked with the [tag:hard-science] tag. It means that answers are expected to be backed up by published research, or verifiable facts. Your answer does not cite any such source.

Comment: I don't think this answer satisfies [the requirements](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/defining-the-boundaries-of-the-hard-science-tag) of the [tag:hard-science] tag.

Comment: It's not difficult science, do you want me to cite a source for the existence of atmospheric pressure? How about gravity? It's pretty obvious that if the problem is low atmospheric pressure, going underwater is going to fix that. To quote wikipedia: "Thus, at about 10 m below the surface, the water exerts twice the pressure (2 atmospheres or 200 kPa) on the body as air at surface level." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater

Comment: @Varrick But the problem _isn't_ low atmospheric pressure, it's low gravity, which going underwater makes worse rather than better.